# How to setup Paypal on a website to accept varying amounts for user to use their credit card?

Tags: paypal

I am very confused by Paypal's site. Does anyone have any direction on how to setup Paypal knowing the following information?

I need users to be able to invoice and use credit cards.
There will be a value that is unknown until the time of checkout.

Comment: Thank you OrganizedChaos. I'm a bit of a beginner and that answer makes sense and I appreciate your input.

Comment: As far as the reason why this is off-topic, I would like to let you know that Paypal redirected me to this site as to where I can ask questions for Paypal support. I have been a user before at stack overflow and understand that this site is very opinionated and I will delete my account again. I find more helpful answers other places, but I was redirected here from Paypal so I thought I'd let all of you know that Paypal redirects people here for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Paypal, they want to see certain POST variables to know who you are, how much is being charged, if there is tax etc... In the past, I have just written some javascript functions to adjust these values before they are submitted.

For example, here is the paypal documentation.  https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_techview_outside

Creating a javascript function to change value="12.99" to value="Whatever" before the user clicks the Pay Now button is one way to do it.

Knowing more about how this value is created etc, would determine how the javascript (or JQuery) function looks.